# position div containing image slider behind all other divs

Tags: css, html, position, z-index

I have an image slider that I'd like to place behind a few other divs. I've played with `postion:absolute` and `position:relative` without much success- everything shifted to one side, as well as `z-index` which made no noticeable changes. I'm thinking I'm missing a step or idea somewhere but am unsure where else to turn/what to look for.

ETA: `<div id="home-slider">` should be behind all else.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsZSE/3/)

html

```
<div id="home">
        <div class="logo">
            <h1><a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/232/232" alt="logo" id="logo" /></a></h1>
        </div><!-- end logo -->

        <div id="slider_mask">
            <div class="slide_container">
                <div class="slide"><p>is where creative <i>je ne sais quoi</i> + business savvy collide.</p></div>
                <div class="slide"><p>is the maker + doer for makers + doers</p></div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <ul>
                    <li>No items.</li>                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="left_button"><a href="#" class="left-arrow" title="left arrow"></a></div>
            <div class="right_button"><a href="#" class="right-arrow" title="right arrow"></a></div>
        </div>

        <div id="home-slider" style="position:relative;">               
             <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/840/420" alt="home-slider" />
        </div>

    </div><!-- end home -->
```

css

```
/* Home */

#home #home-slider {
    height: 420px;
    width: 840px;
}

#home .logo {
    padding-top: 215px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 232px;
}

#home #slider_mask {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 60px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#home #slider_mask .left_button {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 23px;
    height: 25px;
    background: url(img/left-arrow.png);
    text-indent: -99999px;
}

#home #slider_mask .left_button:hover {
    background: url(img/left-arrow-hover.png);
    background-position: 0 0;
}

#home #slider_mask .slide_container {
    float: left;
    font-size: 120%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
}

#home #slider_mask .right_button {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    width: 23px;
    height: 25px;
    background: url(img/right-arrow.png);
    text-indent: -99999px;
}

#home #slider_mask .right_button:hover {
    background: url(img/right-arrow-hover.png);
    background-position: 0 0;
}

#home #slider_mask .slide {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Post a FiddleJS please?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell what you are trying to do. What should cover what in that fiddle? Perhaps some background colors would help, so we can see which div is which.

Comment: You need to include slider in "External Resources" as well as now it's throwing errors. http://jsfiddle.net/dsZSE/2/

Comment: @chiefGui, jsfiddle is located in the text just above the pasted code.

Comment: @ralph.m, replaced slider and logo with colors, should be easier to dissect now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simply removing `overflow: hidden` from here:

```
#home #slider_mask {
width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top: 60px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your inline styles on `#home-slider` and add this to it

```
#home-slider{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  z-index:-1;
}
```